# Views search for labels in select list fields with exposed filters

Tags: views

I created page with Views 3 where users can find other user by entering data in several exposed filters.

That works great, but I have case where user must be able to to enter text, to search by label in select list field. (It has **key | label** structure )

When I expose that filter, it only gives me results on propper key values, but when label is entered, there is no result.

For example if i have **167 | Mathematics** value, 
and i enter 167, it lists users who have choosen that value from select field,
but if i enter "Mathematics", there are no results.

I do not see a kind of option to "search for labels" in select list, and filter result by that.

Is there a way to accomplish this ?

Thanks!